# How to set custom block to not in any region, therefore user can selete region by ownself?

Tags: hooks

This is my custom block hoo_block_info():

```
 function myblock_block_info() {
   $blocks = array();
     if (variable_get('hare_block', 0)) {
       $blocks['abc'] = array(
         'info' => t('test block'),
         'visibility' => 0,
         'status' => TRUE,
         'region' => 'none',
         'weight' => 99,
         'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
       );
     }
   return $blocks;
 }
```

Now by setting 'region'=>'none' there is an error that block region is not defined. Please let me know how to place block in none region?

Answer (score 3):

Simply remove `'region' => 'none'` from hook_block_info().

**region:** (optional) Initial value for theme region within which this block is set. Most modules do not provide an initial value, and any value provided can be modified by a user on the block configuration screen.

> Note: If you set a region that isn't available in the currently
>   enabled theme, the block will be disabled.

Comment: what about 'visibility' => 0, 'status' => TRUE, and 'weight' => 99 ?? should i remove them or not ?

Comment: visibility, status and weight are also optional. You can remove them, while creating custom block you should avoid to add these property, you should configure these all settings through block UI page.

Comment: I just can not remove region property ! I want to use it and also want to display block in region "None".  Moreover i can not use "hook_block_info_alter". Therefore, is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Just curious to know whether it can be done in such way ??

Comment: Provide machine name of 'None' region, I guess it is 'none'.

Comment: I have used 'none' but its does't working and show error undefined region. Moreover, blocked is disabled.

Comment: This mean 'none' region is not there into your theme.

Comment: I am using Bartik theme.

Comment: Bartik theme does not have 'none' region.

Comment: But this is for block ! And it shows 'none' region there while configuring blocks.

Comment: '-None-' means disable. So no need to mention region in hook_block_info

Comment: i have tried '-None-' also . Anything else can be done ?